# Laravel - Retornar valores no layout master

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma aplicação utilizando o laravel 5.5, surgiu a necessidade de inserir um campo dinâmico no footer que fica localizado no layout master, porém, não estou conseguindo retornar os dados nele, não consegui achar uma solução para o meu problema.

A rota principal está configurada para receber a view home, defini no controller para enviar os dados para view, nesta view consigo visualizar os dados corretamente, mas somente nela, porém preciso agora visualizar esses mesmos dados no footer da página e aí precisaria inserir basicamente este trecho no footer para receber os valores.

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i < $maiorTamanho; $i++) {
  echo '<tr>';
    if(sizeof($dataTim) > $i)
    {
      echo '<td>'. $dataTim[$i]->numero .'</td>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<td></td>';
    }

    if(sizeof($dataVivo) > $i)
    {
      echo '<td>'. $dataVivo[$i]->numero .'</td>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<td></td>';
    }

    if(sizeof($dataClaro) > $i)
    {
      echo '<td>'. $dataClaro[$i]->numero .'</td>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<td></td>';
    }

    if(sizeof($dataOi) > $i)
    {
      echo '<td>'. $dataOi[$i]->numero .'</td>';
    }
    else {
      echo '<td></td>';
    }
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

O que preciso fazer para retornar os valores no layout master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retornar algum dado especificamente para o layout "master" não é possível.

Uma das soluções, seria instanciar a model direto na view.

por exemplo:

```
@foreach(\Auth::user()->notifications()->orderby('id', 'desc')->limit(10)->pluck('data') as $notification)
    <li>
         <a>
             <span class="bold">
                 <span>
                      {{$notification[0]['title']}}
                 </span>
             </span>
             <br>
             <span class="message">
                 {!! $notification[0]['message'] !!}
             </span>
          </a>
     </li>
@endforeach
```